# Error for the multi normal in JAGS,Compilation error on line 12. Attempt to redefine node q[1:3]

Tags: r

```
cat("
model {
l ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
g ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
o ~ dunif(0, 1)
p ~ dunif(0, 1)
for(i in 1:nSites) {
  N[i,1] ~ dpois(l)
  y[i,1] ~ dbin(p, N[i,1])
  for(t in 2:nYears) {
      pi<-c(1-p_b-p_c,p_b,p_c)
      q[1:3]~dmulti(pi[1:3],N[i,t-1])
      Mit[i,t-1]<-q[1]
      M[i,t] ~ dpois(l)
      new<-o*(Mit[i,t-1])
      D[i,t] ~ dpois(new)
      N[i,t]<-M[i,t]+D[i,t]
      y[i,t] ~ 
    }
  }
}
", fill=TRUE)
```

there is an error called
Compilation error on line 12.
Attempt to redefine node q[1:3]
I want to use multinormal to
participate N[i,t-1] into the matrix M[i,t],use the probability vector c(1-Pb-Pc,Pb,Pc),however, I met some errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `q` vector is being overwritten for each `t` in `2:nYears`. I would index `q` by `t-1` and `i` because the it looks like it should vary by site and year (given the inputs).

```
cat("
model {
l ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
g ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
o ~ dunif(0, 1)
p ~ dunif(0, 1)
for(i in 1:nSites) {
  N[i,1] ~ dpois(l)
  y[i,1] ~ dbin(p, N[i,1])
  for(t in 2:nYears) {
      pi<-c(1-p_b-p_c,p_b,p_c)
      q[1:3,i,t-1]~dmulti(pi[1:3],N[i,t-1])
      Mit[i,t-1]<-q[1]
      M[i,t] ~ dpois(l)
      new<-o*(Mit[i,t-1])
      D[i,t] ~ dpois(new)
      N[i,t]<-M[i,t]+D[i,t]
      y[i,t] ~ dbin(p, N[i,t])
    }
  }
}
", fill=TRUE)
```

Without a reproducible example (e.g., a dataset to go along with the model) I'm not 100% sure you are trying to model, but assuming that `q` is a derived variable in the model this should work (i.e., you are not supplying data `q` into the model that is a vector of length 3).

Comment: Thanks ,However , I met a new problem after your suggestions: It said Unable to find appropriate sampler.Do you know why? It looks associate with the dmulti function

Comment: my q is a matrix in my case. I am a beginner user of the jags. Could you explain to me what is the meaning of q[1:3,i,t-1]? It looks becomes a three dimensional array instead of  matrix . Thanks

Comment: What are the dimensions you are expecting to have for the `q` matrix? Right now it varies by site, year, and category (1:3).